# Display new shared preferences value every time page is loaded in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have a mobile game which saves max score value after the game is finished and in the main page I display that max score. Because I load shared preferences data in main page `initState()` function, unless user closes and reopens the app the max score does not change on the main page. Any solution ideas ?

this is play_game.dart file where I save results to sharedpreferences when user finishes the game:

```
  Future saveResults() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    int maxSoz = int.parse(preferences.getString('max_soz'));
    int maxPoint = int.parse(preferences.getString('max_xal'));
    if (speed > maxPoint && soz > maxSoz) {
      preferences.setString('max_xal', speed.toString());
      preferences.setString('max_soz', soz.toString());
    }
  }
```

and this is the landing_page.dart where I display the max scores.
I have a function to load sharedpreferences data:

```
  Future loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      this.maxSoz = preferences.getString('max_soz') ?? '0';
      this.maxPoint = preferences.getString('max_xal') ?? '0';
    });
  }
```

and to load data, I mention that function in initState():

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }
```

`initState()` loades data (executes `loadData()` function) when page is initialized first time. If gamer, after finishing the game, comes back to landing page from play_game page by clicking to "go back" button, the new max scores are not being shown on landing page because, as you may guess, function `loadData()` only gets executed when page initalized (by `initState()`).

Comment: If you put some code then it will be easy for us to know where you are facing the problem.

Comment: Look into the bloc pattern how to propagade state between the UI and model

Comment: Agree with @sagar...post your code. Bloc might be using a steamroller to crack a peanut, imho.

Comment: tried to clarify my problem. hope you understand all

Comment: use FutureBuilder, such issue discussed in every second topic million times already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `await` in front of your `Navigator`, for example:

```
...
...

final exit = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/pages/play_game");
if (exit == true) {
    loadData();
} 

...
...
```

> Notes: I am assuming that your `play_game.dart` will return something, for example `bool`

Comment: I figured out that using FutureBuilder will be only solution, but your method is also useful if there are no much pages in game. Thanks for your time!